# Getting Yaru Icon Theme on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, icon-themes

I want to be able to get the Yaru icon theme from Ubuntu 19.04 on Ubuntu 18.04, instead of the default Adwaita theme. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have ripped the official Yaru icon theme from 19.04. Here is how you can get it on 18.04:

1. Download Yaru.zip from http://gg.gg/YaruTheme. If you see "Google Drive can't scan this file for viruses", just ignore it and download anyway.
2. Extract the Yaru folder from the archive.
3. Press CTRL+H in Nautilus to show hidden folders.
4. Click on the Yaru folder and hit CTRL+C to copy it.
5. From the home directory, go to .local/share/icons
6. Inside this folder, hit CTRL+V to paste the Yaru folder.
7. Install Tweaks with `sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`.
8. Open Tweaks and go to the Appearance tab
9. Change the "Icons" dropdown from Adwaita to Yaru.
10. Done! You should now see your icons have changed to the Yaru icon theme.

Answer (score 2):

you can download the source files from github web page for Yaru theme ( https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru )

and then copy paste the `Suru` directory to your preferred location.

for example any of `$HOME/.icons` or `$HOME/.local/share/icons/` or `/usr/share/icons/`

below pics are self-explanatory

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

You can rename the folder to `Yaru` or may leave it as it is `Suru`

Then you can either use `gnome-tweaks` (`sudo apt install gnome-tweaks`) or command line to choose the Icon Theme

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme Suru
```

for resetting to default theme

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme
```

[image]